# Lower resolutions appear abnormally blurry on laptop

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, radeon, display-resolution, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 9200 equipped with Mobility Radeon 9700 graphics with a max resolution of 1920x1200. I have both XP and Lubuntu installed, and I've noticed something particularly irking. Lower resolutions (say, 640x480) work absolutely fine in XP, and are sharp and clear. When booted in Lubuntu 18.04, however, the image appears blurred, as if some sort of odd software scaling is going on. I will mention that I'm not using proprietary drivers, as they don't support this version of Lubuntu anyway.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw -C display` Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Only 960x600 will look decent; the rest will look awful, since 960x600 is 1/4 of your design resolution. LXDE does not have the ability to make an LCD look decent unless you use the design resolution or an integer fraction (e.g., 960x600) of the design resolution.